# SQL Server Linked Server INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server

I have problem with linked server at store procedure, I want to get data from linked server then insert into table.

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GETPRODRECORD]
    @PR_NO varchar(10)=''
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @OPENQUERY nvarchar(4000), 
            @TSQL nvarchar(4000), 
            @LinkedServer nvarchar(4000)  

    CREATE TABLE AAA (PR varchar(10))

    SET @LinkedServer = 'LS'

    SET @OPENQUERY = 'INSERT INTO AAA SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY('+ @LinkedServer + ','''
    SET @TSQL = 'SELECT PSHN9G FROM F9G00 WHERE PSHN9G='''''+@PR_NO+''''')'

    EXEC (@OPENQUERY+@TSQL)
END
```

My problem is that the `EXEC` is not running, when I try to insert manually with code below is working

```
INSERT INTO AAA(PR) 
    SELECT PSHN9G 
    FROM OPENQUERY(WAVEDLIB,'SELECT PSHN9G FROM F9G00 WHERE PSHN9G=''XXXXXXX'')
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: `PRINT @OPENQUERY+@TSQL` and see if it's identical to your manually run query...

Comment: where in the proc are you assigning @LinkedServer ?

Comment: already edit var @linkedserver, still not run

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use `OPENQUERY` and `EXECUTE`, you can simply reference LinkedServer if you know which DB is your table into:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GETPRODRECORD]
    @PR_NO varchar(10)=''
AS 
BEGIN
--No need to CREATE TABLE every time you exec SP. SELECT INTO #temp table instead.
SELECT PSHN9G INTO #temp FROM WAVEDLIB.DBName.dbo.F9G00 WHERE PSHN9G=@PR_NO
SELECT * FROM #temp
END
```